# How to redirect a specified directory to other sites using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, request

I need to redirect all files in a **particular directory of a particular site** to the same directory of other site. For example:

`http://www.mysite.com/dir/file1.html  ---> http://www.mysite2.com/dir/file1.html`

`http://www.mysite.com/dir/file2.html ---> http://www.mysite2.com/dir/file2.html`

`http://www.mysite.com/dir/file3.html ---> http://www.mysite2.com/dir/file3.html`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only redirect the one directory, try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /dir/(.*) http://www.mysite2.com/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you even used a search engine?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /dir/(.*) http://www.mysite2.com/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```